# using broad cast receiver along with activity

Tags: android

i am working on a project with many activities but when trying to code a broad cast receiver within a class the broadcast receiver is not working though i have given permission to manifest file. with reciver.

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReciever" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
mContext = context;
mIntent = intent;
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any mistakes with the XML excerpt that you posted. However, there might be an error in the tag `android:name`. This should be a fully qualified class name (for example `com.example.project.ReportReceiver`). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, `.ReportReceiver`), it is appended to the package name specified in the `<manifest>` element. Using that shortcut, your package name should be something like `package="com.example.project"`. In your case, you should check the whole package name before `.IncomingCallReciever`.

**EDIT:**

Check for problems here particularly:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
    actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
```

Remove the `>` after `android:priority="1"` - that's a syntax problem, it should work once you correct that.

Comment: the package name is correct, but the thing is that. i have whole set of other activites. then one such funtion of my application is to read the receive call and reject it, (i also tosted some info) but nothing is happening if any incomming callls cums in. but when i am using the broadcast receiver class solely in different project its working. i just cant get y isnt it working in this package.

Comment: please help with this context.

Comment: Check the EDITS in the answer.hope this helps.Do let know if still it doesnt.